# login to external url and come back to angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My problem is that I have and external url, I need to call this external url (created by another client) and after I need to come back into home page. I do

```
 <button class="altro" title=" (click)="effettuaLoginExternal($event)">login</button>
```

in my ts I do:

```
  effettuaLoginExternal(event) {

   
      window.location.href="/external/login";
}
```

when I Do  `window.location.href="/external/login";` open this external url and I can insert the username and password but I cannot back to angular application after I click on button "ok" . I don't have the code of this external url. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Unless the remote site was willing to actively support you in this by implementing _something_ that would help make this possible, from their end, there is no way to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If the user needs to leave your site and **interact with a third-party site**, then the **only** way they are going to return to your site is if the third party-side sends them back.

---

The closest you could come without the cooperation of the third-party would be to open their site in a new window or a frame. You would not be able to collect any data from the third-party site (e.g. you could not confirm the user logged into the third-party site successfully) and you would depend on the user to click back on the window for your site when they were ready.

Comment: If the third party side return value how can i catch? technically with a POST?

Comment: @Doppu — I said "You would not be able to collect any data from the third-party site". No means no.